# Getting the probability function, from the cumulative probability function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a discrete stochastic variable $V$, defined by;
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
V = 0 & \text{ if } X < \frac{1}{6} \\
V = 1 & \text{ if } \frac{1}{6} \leq X < \frac{3}{6} \\
V = 2 & \text{ if } X \geq \frac{3}{6}
\end{array}
\right.
$$ 
How would I go about finding the probability function for $V$?

The expected output is;
$$
f_{V}\left(v\right) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{6} & \text{ if } v = 0 \\
\frac{2}{6} & \text{ if } v = 1 \\
\frac{1}{2} & \text{ if } v = 2
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I believe that $V$ is defined by the cumulative probability function, so I'll have to somehow subtract the higher possibilities from the lower? - Is it as simple as;
$
f_{V}\left(v\right) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}F_{V}(v)
$
?

Comment: And what perchance is the distribution of random variable $X$ - currently unstated?

Comment: Oh, $X$ is a stochastic variable with $X \sim R\left(0,1\right)$, therefore it's probability density function is; $f_{X}\left(x\right) = 1 \text{ if } x \in \left] 0, 1 \right[$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: So, what then is P(X<1/6) and P(1/6 < X < 3/6)  and P(X > 3/6) ...

Comment: $P\left(X < \frac{1}{6}\right) = \int_{x=0}^{\frac{1}{6}} 1 = \frac{1}{6}$, and I just checked it with $P\left(X > \frac{3}{6}\right)$, it works! - Thanks!

Comment: As for $P\left(\frac{1}{6} < X < \frac{3}{6}\right)$ is this equal to; $\left(\int_{x=\frac{1}{6}}^{1} 1\right) - \left(\int_{x=0}^{\frac{3}{6}} 1\right)$? - Nevermind, just figured it myself, it's obviously; $\int_{x=\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{3}{6}} 1$!